# create calendar array by moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, momentjs

I want to create array like this.

```js
var date_ = [
{ "DateText": "Mon - 2nd April", "Date": "2/4/2017", "WeekNumber" : 13 },
{ "DateText": "Tue - 3rd April", "Date": "3/4/2017", "WeekNumber": 14 },
{ "DateText": "Wed - 4th April", "Date": "4/4/2017", "WeekNumber": 14 }
];
```

I got everything just this 2nd, 3rd and 4th number convention is remaining, can you check my piece of code.

```js
var date_ = []; 

var prevDate = moment().subtract(15, 'days');
var nextDate = moment().add(15, 'days');

var start = new Date(prevDate);
var end = new Date(nextDate);

while(start < end){
   date_.push(
      {
        "DateText" : moment(start).format('ddd - DD MMM'),
        "Date" : moment(start).format('DD/MM/YYYY'),
        "WeekNumber" : moment(start).week()
      }
    );
   var newDate = start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
   start = new Date(newDate);  
}

console.log(date_);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `Do` token see [Display Format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

```
moment(start).format('ddd - Do MMM')
```

```js
var date_ = [];

var prevDate = moment().subtract(15, 'days');
var nextDate = moment().add(15, 'days');

while (prevDate.isBefore(nextDate)) {
  date_.push({
    "DateText": prevDate.format('ddd - Do MMM'),
    "Date": prevDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'),
    "WeekNumber": prevDate.week()
  });
  prevDate.add(1, 'days');
}

console.log(date_);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: +1 for the good answer, but I suggest to compare moment objects using [`isBefore`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/) instead of using `<`

Comment: @VincenzoC, I only focused on OP problem area _I got everything just this 2nd, 3rd and 4th number convention is remaining_ You can modify the answer